# Can I enable "click scrolling" for an Evoluent VerticalMouse 4 on OSX?

Tags: macos, mouse, scrolling

My older Microsoft laser mouse had a feature I miss: clicking the scroll wheel put the mouse into a scrolling mode, where a little circular icon appeared on screen, and moving the cursor made the page scroll. This worked on OSX.

Can I program the VerticalMouse to do this? I don't see such an option in the settings menu in System Preferences (which I got by installing [the drivers](http://evoluent.com/support/download/)).

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like auto scroll.  In OS X, it is a function in Firefox when you do a middle click.  Since you do have the Evoluent software installed, you can program any button you like as the middle click, including the scroll wheel.

In Firefox, the middle click will also open links in new tabs.  Also, if you click on a tab, it closes it.

What the middle button does depends on the program.  In OS X, I know Firefox uses it.  Other browsers and programs may behave differently.

If you don't have the Evoluent software installed, the button below the scroll wheel is a middle click by default.